# Will my incognito windows be recovered if the computer shut down?

Tags: private-browsing

I was on a website that wasn't necessarily PG-rated, however the tab was opened on in [incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en).

The battery died and my computer shut down, before I got the chance to close the window.
I found the charger, but the computer was not responding to my attempt to charge it which leads me to believe that there was a problem with the connection port.

I want to know if the windows in incognito mode can be recovered (or will recover) when the computer is fixed. The laptop was not my own, so I do not want the next user to have seen my activity as soon as they log on.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not restore incognito mode tabs after a crash, as they are never actually saved into your browsing history (or shouldn't be, if everything works right). You will only be prompted to reopen your regular tabs.

Answer (score 0):

No, Incognito tabs don't save history anyway so there is no way for them to be restored. Only normal tabs can be recovered.